# How to use WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control settings in the customizer preview?

Tags: theme-customizer

I'm using the WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control in order to allow the user to upload and crop an image in the Customizer and use it as a background image for a widgetized area. It looks something like this:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'home-bg', array(    
                'sanitize_callback' => 'absint',
                'transport'         => 'postMessage',
            ) );

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'home-bg', array(
        'section'     => 'home_bgs',
        'label'       => 'Section Background',
        'flex_width'  => true,
        'flex_height' => true,
        'width'       => 1920,
        'height'      => 500,
    ) ) );
```

In the php code I use `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` to get the image url&height and use them to output css in a way similar to twentysixteen theme. The issue is with the customizer preview since Cropped_Image_Control stores the ID.

**My question is: what would be the best way to get the image url and height in the customizer preview?**

Additional info/notes: in the `/wp-admin/js/customize-controls.js` file under `api.MediaControl` there a function called [setAttachmentDataAndRenderContent](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/js/customize-controls.js#L4221). In this function, there's a comment that says `Send attachment information to the preview for possible use in postMessage transport` and part of the code is:

`wp.customize.previewer.send( control.setting.id + '-attachment-data', this.attributes );`

The way i understand it, if I use the following code in my customize-preview.js file, I should be able to easily access what i need:

```
wp.customize.bind( 'preview-ready', function() {
        wp.customize.preview.bind( 'home-bg-attachment-data', function( data ) {
            console.info( data );
        } );
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. The if statement never seems to be true so the attachment information is never sent. I think it's because of this [36521](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/36521).